# Rails 4 Paperclip FactoryGirl file uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip, factory-bot, bdd

I have a FactoryGirl :product factory that uses `fixture_file_upload` to set  `image`, which is a Paperclip attachment.

```
    image { fixture_file_upload "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/images/product.png", 'image/png' }
```

`fixture_file_upload` works fine, **but** every time a test creates a new Product using the factory, Paperclip creates a new file in `publicproducts/<id>/original.png`. **This is the issue.**. Filling a the folder `publicproducts` on each test run is not acceptable.

The first workaround I can think of is the solution mentioned in https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Cleanup-after-your-Rspec-tests

Have you solved this problem in another way?

Comment: The link you have given is the best way I think, I use the same, I have a folder named `upload_test` in which the attachments goes and I remove all the files from it using the same.

Comment: @Deep yep, you convinced me to use the same approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution, also mentioned by Deep is to:

- specify that paperclip in test environment should upload files to folder `test_uploads`,
- modify factory_girl factories to upload a fixture from ex. `spec/fixtures/images/filename.extension`,
- add an after all cleanup block in `rails_helper.rb`

In code:

`config/environments/test.rb`

```
  ...
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    path: ':rails_root/test_uploads/:class/:id/:attachment/:filename.:extension',
    url: ':rails_root/test_uploads/:class/:id/:attachment/:filename.:extension'
  }
  ...
```

`spec/factories/products.rb`

```
image { fixture_file_upload "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/images/product.png", 'image/png' }
```

`rails_helper.rb`

```
  ...
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

  config.after(:all) do
    if Rails.env.test?
      test_uploads = Dir["#{Rails.root}/test_uploads"]
      FileUtils.rm_rf(test_uploads)
    end
  end
  ...
```